# Cannot use a positional argument after a named argument $data for add cpomment in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio

this is my eror:
Cannot use a positional argument after a named argument
Declared in:
public function ServerData::add_comment($data) void
Source:
.../ServerData.php
`data` on [www.php.net](http://www.php.net)

```
public function add_comment($data){

   $product_id= array_key_exists(key:'product_id', $data) ? $data['product_id'] : 0;
   if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['comment'])){

       $name=$_POST['name'];
       $email=$_POST['email'];
       $comment=$_POST['comment'];

       $new_comment=$this->connection->prepare("INSERT INTO `comment` ( `name`, `email`, `content`, `product_id`, `parent_id`, `status`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, 0, 1)");
       $new_comment->execute([$name,$email,$comment,$product_id]);


   }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Try swapping $data and key:'product_id'. Named arguments are arguments, which need to be called with their name before and as the error implies, you need to call normal / "positional" arguments first, and only then your named arguments. Please provide a code snippet next time except for a screenshot.

Comment: Don't use photos for code. Upload code instead

Comment: @fusion Hi my friend, I put the code

Comment: @Mayank Hi my friend, I put the code

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, **Cannot use a positional argument after a named argument $data**, you have to include positional arguments before names arguments in function invocation.
Therefore the correct code would be:

```
$product_id= array_key_exists($data,key:'product_id') ? $data['product_id'] : 0;
```